# Is $M_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})$ in reduced row echelon form with n pivots, thus an equation system $Ax = b$ is for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$ solvable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $n \in  \mathbb{N} $ and $M_{n,n} (\mathbb{R})$ in reduced row echelon form with n pivots, thus an equation system $Ax = b$ is for every $b \in \mathbb{R}$ solvable?

My reasoning:
A pivot in every row means that the linear system $Ax=b$ has at least one solution, for every b.

If every column has a pivot, then the linear system $Ax=b$ has at most one solution.

If both hold (which can happen only if A is a square matrix), we get that the system $Ax=b$ has unique solution for every b.

So I guess that it's true, but I'm not sure that my reasoning is good enough.

Comment: Yes, this is true. This is also equivalent to saying that the matrix $A$ is invertible, and hence, the only solution is given by $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: is there a reasoning without using the fact that the matrix is invertible?

Comment: You can also say that when you echelon the matrix, then it does not change the number of solution of the system. And if the matrix is triangular with nonzero diagonal coefficients, then it is clear that the system has always exactly one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea it’s ok, you can check by multiplying $Ax$, the you will have something like $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1}x_1&\dots&a_{1,n}x_n\\
&\ddots& \vdots\\&&
a_{n,n}x_n
\end{pmatrix},$$ then you have an unique solution for $$a_{n,n}x_n=b_n,$$ and becaus the matrix it’s on $M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and it has $n$ pivots, $a_{j,j}\neq0$ for each $j$ and then $$x_n=\cfrac{b_n}{a_{n,n}}$$ and you can replace this $x_n$ on the $(n-1)$-th row and go on until you get that unique solution.